# How to show all group content if user is a group member

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

i am new to programming and doing a small project(simple bug tracker) using django-rest-framework.

so far i have a Bugs model and if the user is logged in, he can see the bugs reported by him.Now i created a new model called Team in which one can make a team by adding email ids (i used MultiEmailField to store the list of emails).My requirement is that if the logged in user's email is present in any Team, the user should be able to see all the team members activities.I dont know how to accomplish this .please help me.Thanks in advance

```
#bugs model#
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Bugs(models.Model):
    issueId = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000, blank=True)
    actualResult = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    expectedResult = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    status = models.TextField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="bugs", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


#team model#


from django.db import models
from multi_email_field.fields import MultiEmailField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Team(models.Model):
    projectTitle = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=True)
    durationFrom = models.DateField(null=True)
    durationEnd = models.DateField(null=True)
    teamMembers = MultiEmailField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="team", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)





#api.py#

from bugs.models import Bugs
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import BugsSerializer


class BugsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = BugsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.bugs.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Part one: make Team a many to many relation to User. Don't use the email addresses as a reference in the database. And BTW Django has a Group model already you might want to use or extend that.

Comment: @KlausD.  Thank you so much. I have decided to work with Django Group model.